# If $R \subset S$ is a domain and $S \subseteq \mathrm{Quot}(R)$ then $\mathrm{ann}_{R}(S/R) \ne {0}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $S$ be a commutative ring. If $R \subseteq S$ is a domain, $S \subseteq\mathrm{Quot}(R)$ and $S$ is finitely generated as $R$-module, then $\mathrm{ann}_{R}(S/R) \ne {0}$.

Remark: $\mathrm{ann}_{R}(S/R) \ne {0}$ refers to the annihilator, i.e. $\mathrm{ann}_{R}(S/R) := \{a \in R \mid aS \subseteq R\}$.

I do not see how I could do this, but I think the assumption that $S \subseteq\mathrm{Quot}(R)$ is important. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathrm{Quot}(R)$ there are $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $S=Rx_1 + \cdots + Rx_n$. But any $x_i$ can be written $x_i=\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ with $a_i$, $b_i \in R \setminus \{ 0 \}$. I advise you to consider the element $b=b_1 \cdots b_n$ for your problem

Comment: +1. The key idea here is "clearing denominators".

Comment: Could you please explain why there are such $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in $Quot(R)$, is this a standard fact?

Comment: @3nondatur: by hypothesis, $S$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

Comment: Oh sorry. Thanks a lot for your answer, I got it now.